# Improve page speed when querying database

Tags: mysql, flask, query-optimization, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using a Flask for one application I am working on, together with sqlalchemy and MySQL database for storing data. Jinja2 is used for templating. While developing, everything was OK, but now when the larger dataset is used, I am getting very slow rendering of some of the webpages that contain a lot of data. For example, a list of users is handled by this code:

```
def users():
    q = Users.query.all()
    out = []
    for i in q: 
        try:
            something_i_need = Table.query.filter_by(email=i.email).order_by(Table.date).first().id
        except:
            something_i_need = 0
        out.append({
                'id': i.id,
                'last_name': i.last_name,
                'first_name': i.first_name,
                'middle_name': i.middle_name,
                'phone': i.phone,
                'team': i.team,
                'status': i.status,
                'needed': something_i_need,
                'some_more_data': i.some_more_data
            })
    return render_template('users.html', list_of_users=out)
```

The data is a bit simplified, since theres more fields in the list. The call to this location, which queries around 2000 users at a time takes more than 10 seconds, and then the load of the page takes 10-20 as well. The table is wrapped by the following theme functions, [first table from this link](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic&page=index.html), and although disabling sorting functions on some columns helped, its still very slow.

So, I am wondering, how can I optimize this process or the generation of the template in order to make this faster? I am running this on an Amazon EC2 instance, with `Python 2.7.3 and mod_wsgi, Flask 0.9, Flask-SQLAlchemy=0.16, Jinja2==2.7, MySQL-python=1.2.4, SQLAlchemy=0.8.1`. The one "obvious" solution, making a pagination and returning 100 or so records at a time would really work since the list has to contain all of the users for sorting purposes (date mostly), so that solution would the last resort.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you are running N+1 queries (where `N` is the total number of users in the `User` table) where 1 would do far better:

```
User.query \
        .outerjoin(Table, User.email == Table.email) \
        .order_by(User.email, Table.date)
```

will get you all users with all of their entries in `Table` ordered by each user's email address and then by the date column in `Table`.  We use an `outerjoin` rather than a `join` to ensure that we get ever user, even if they don't have an entry in `Table`.

Now, this is not quite what we need - we really want to get the *latest* entry in `Table` if one exists.  There is probably a better way to do this, but here's a simple example with a subquery:

```
last_entry = Table.query \
                  .group_by(Table.email) \
                  .order_by(Table.date) \
                  .subquery()

# Assuming that db is your Flask-SQLAlchemy extension
results = db.session.query(User, last_entry.c.id)  \
    .outerjoin(last_entry, User.email == last_entry.c.email)
```

Then you can just materialize the query with a call to `all` and you'll be off to the races:

```
return render_template('users.html', list_of_users=results.all())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now it makes sense that I am making a couple of thousands of request without any valid reason.
However, I am getting an error with this code, "AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'id'" in that "results = ..." line.

Comment: @wont_compile - apologies, I missed the `.c.` - we need to access the `columns` attribute of the subquery object.

Comment: Thanks once again, that was helpful, at least partially :D I am getting a new error now: "TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable"
Also on the result line. I have circumvented it somehow, by removing the (User, last_entry.c.id) after the query portion, but that resulted in not getting the last_entry at all in the table, so I'm again missing something. Also, I am curious about how the results are then used in the templating engine, same as the class properites? I managed to get the data by using user[id] and things like that, but couldn't do it for the invoice (probably due to the query).

Comment: @wont_compile - Yep, there was another issue there - I've updated the results call to use the right `query`.

Comment: No errors now, but my output table is empty, but I can see it has rows, just no data in it, so its populated but I appear to not be referencing the list inside correctly. I use this:
{% for user in users %}
<tr>user['first_name'], user['last_name']</tr>
{% endfor %}

This worked before, so how does your code affect the output?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly do the querying Asynchronously. Secondly maintain a conditional flow, where you should display the returned results in chunks.
for example:

```
//get lenght of returning cursor
if(//length of returning cursor is greator thatn 10 or something..)
 {
  //Run a loop here and update your UI on UI thread for every 10 values.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, since the site is generated by the templating engine, I am unaware of the method to render it "partially", all I know is to pass a list or some other arguments to the template file at once, and then parse and iterate over those ones. Similar goes to the query, since its done on the server and then the results are passed to the templating engine, I am also unsure how to make it async, especially given in mind that the table has some routines on it own (jquery) which happen on document load, so Im unsure how would that affect those.